# How do I associate/link a cell with another cell in Excel?

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have an Excel workbook with a column for first name, and other column for last name. I need to alphabetize sort the last name column from A-Z. When I sort the last name column, I need the first name column to adjust with the last name. How can I link or associate cells from the first name column to the last name column, so that when I sort the last name column, the first name is with the correct last name?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the Sort command on the Data ribbon. If your data is in adjacent cells, the sort will include all adjacent columns.

Or, make your life easier, select the data and click on Auto Filter. Then you have filter and sort drop-downs in the column header.

Comment: That worked, thank you.